# WinRT Background Task with Time Trigger Error

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, background-process, sqlite-net, winrt-component

I have defined my `BackgroundTask` as follows:

```
public sealed class BackgroundSynchronization:IBackgroundTask
{
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            //code
            //Network Calls
            //Updating Local DB (SQLite)

            myRepository.Save(entity);   // Saves entity in SQLite Table, and Entity has a  Current DateTime field too.

            deferral.Complete();
        }
}
```

And `TaskRegister` class as:

```
public static class BackgroundTaskRegister {

    public static  BackgroundTaskRegistration RegisterBackgroundTask(string taskEntryPoint,string taskName,IBackgroundTrigger trigger,IBackgroundCondition condition)
    {
        foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {

            if (cur.Value.Name == taskName)
            {
                return (BackgroundTaskRegistration)(cur.Value);
            }
        }

        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

        builder.Name = taskName;
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
        builder.SetTrigger(trigger);

        if (condition != null)
        {
            builder.AddCondition(condition);
        }

        BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();

        return task;
    }

}
```

And I have registered the trigger in my app as:

```
    TimeTrigger myTrigger = new TimeTrigger(15, false);
    await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

    string entryPoint = "BackgroundTask.BackgroundSynchronization";
    string taskName = "Example per 15 minute background task";
    BackgroundTaskRegistration tsk = BackgroundTaskRegister.RegisterBackgroundTask(entryPoint, taskName, myTrigger, null);

    tsk.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(OnCompleted);
```

I also have an `OnComplete` method in my app:

```
 private async void OnCompleted(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
 {
            var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            var message = settings.Values["backgroundSyncStatus"].ToString();
            var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile file;
            var x = await File.DoesFileExistInLocalAsync("BackgroundTaskSucceedLog.txt");

            if (!x)
                file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("BackgroundTaskSucceedLog.txt");
            else
               file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("BackgroundTaskSucceedLog.txt");

            await Windows.Storage.FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, message.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
 }
```

The background tasks triggers successfully, and the data is saved to SQLite DB `myRepository.Save(entity);` table only for the first run. 
I came to this conclusion as I had logged the entries in `OnComplete` method.

The logger results confused me more.

Logger results:

```
2/16/2015 10:51:41 PM     <-- Data Saved in SQLite for this entry
2/16/2015 11:07:03 PM
2/16/2015 11:22:26 PM
2/16/2015 11:37:39 PM
2/16/2015 11:52:51 PM
2/17/2015 5:33:00 AM       <-- Data Saved in SQLite for this entry
```

The data in SQLite is saved only for the first Background Task "for a day". 
I tried to debug the `BackgroundTask`. The first run everything runs smoothly, but in the subsequent run the compiler jumps directly to the `OnComplete` method after reaching `myRepository.Save(entity);`. Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your background task might be killed by the system if it is using too much resources. Lock screen application have only 2 seconds of CPU time every 15 minutes. You can get more details here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx

You can also get the reason about why your background task is suspended using the [CheckResult()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskcompletedeventargs.checkresult.aspx) methods from BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs.

In your task completed event handler you can do the following:

```
private async void OnCompleted(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        args.CheckResult();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // add a log/breakpoint here
    }
}
```

It should at least given you some insight of what is going wrong.